# Cómo devovler un listado de objetos generico en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una clase que se conecta a una base de datos SQL Server para hacer el CRUD. Estoy tratando de hacerlo lo más genérico posible, pero no me sale y no entiendo el por qué.

En mi database hay 3 tablas, Animales, Cuidadores y Refugios.

Muestro aquí un ejemplo:

```
public List<object> ObtenerListado(object generico)
{
    ZoocanDB db = new ZoocanDB();

    if(generico.GetType() == typeof(Animale))
    {
        return db.Animales.ToList();
    }

    if(generico.GetType() == typeof(Cuidadore))
    {
        return db.Cuidadores.ToList();
    }
            
    if(generico.GetType() == typeof(Refugio))
    {
        return db.Refugios.ToList();
    }
}
```

Trataba de hacer que devolviera un listado de objetos genérico, pero no me está saliendo como yo esperaba. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En programación existe el **principio de Responsabilidad Única** que establece que una **clase**, **módulo** etc. **debe tener responsabilidad sobre una sola parte de la funcionalidad proporcionada por el software**, tu diseño de clases tal como lo tienes hecho viola este principio, ya que no tiene una única responsabilidad sino 3, lo que debes hacer es crear 3 clases, una para la gestión de los animales, otra para la gestión de los cuidadores y otra para la gestión de los refugios, donde cada clase por separado tendrá sus propias responsabilidades haciendo  que cada clase tenga una alta cohesión, ya que cada una hace lo que le toca y nada más.

Otro principio que deben tener tu diseño de clases es una **alta cohesión** y un **bajo acoplamiento**.

**Alta cohesión** es cuando tienes una clase que hace un trabajo bien definido. La baja cohesión es cuando una clase hace muchos trabajos que no tienen mucho en común.

**Bajo acoplamiento** sugiere que la clase debería tener las **menores dependencias** posibles.

En tu caso específico tu acoplamiento es alto ya que en cada clase haces uso de la **clase ZoocanDB**, esto es un tema más avanzado y existen varios patrones de diseño para hacer que el acoplamiento sea lo más bajo posible, por ejemplo la **inyección de dependencias**.

Atendiendo a todo lo anterior te propongo el siguiente diseño de clases:

```
public class ControladoraAnimal
{
    private ZoocanDB db;   

    public ControladoraAnimal(ZoocanDB zoocanDB)
    {
        db = zoocanDB;
    }

    public List<Animal> ListarAnimales()
    {
        return db.Animales.ToList();
    }
}

public class ControladoraCuidador
{
    private ZoocanDB db;   

    public ControladoraCuidador(ZoocanDB zoocanDB)
    {
        db = zoocanDB;
    }

    public List<Cuidador> ListarCuidadores()
    {
        return db.Cuidadores.ToList();
    }
}

public class ControladoraRefugio
{
    private ZoocanDB db;   

    public ControladoraRefugio(ZoocanDB zoocanDB)
    {
        db = zoocanDB;
    }

    public List<Refugio> ListarRefugios()
    {
        return db.Refugios.ToList();
    }
}
```

Una forma de amortiguar el alto acoplamiento es pasar el objeto como parámetro al constructor de la clase que lo va a usar, en este diseño que te propongo el objeto de tipo **ZoocanDB** se pasa como **parámetro al constructor de cada clase controladora**, pero existen técnicas más refinadas te toca a ti investigarlas.

La importancia que tiene seguir estos principios de diseño entre otras cosas es que hacen que el código sea más fácil de mantener, lo hacen más legible, más reutilizable, menos propenso a tener errores etc.

Te recomiendo que investigues sobre el **principio SOLID**.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias. Así lo tenía, pero quería saber si podía hacerlo de la otra forma. Gracias.

Comment: lo que dices es correcto, pero esta mal respondida la respuesta, además que tu también violando el principio, para este caso se puede usar clase genérica, que es `T`, también dejo el resultado esperado

Comment: @Japv en tu respuesta estas inyectando `ZoocanDB db` que supongo que es la Base de datos, en los tres controladores, en ese caso es mejor crear una interfaz y ahí mismo inyectar `ZoocanDB db`, sin tener que hacerlo en cada controlador, si su proyecto crece, se estará inyectando `N` veces en el controlador, y retornando `N` veces el listado

Comment: @Daniel Yo no estoy violando nada, yo solo le explique una parte, la otra le toca a el investigarla, tambien puedes responder con tu propia respuesta, vuelve a leer mi respuesta y veras que le hablo claramente de la inyeccion de dependencias

Comment: Pero además @Daniel si nos ponemos exquisitos tu tambien violas en cierta medida el acoplamiento ya que usas la herencia entre clases, vuelvete a leer mi respuesta y veras que yo le hablo de todo lo que deje de hacer

Comment: @Japv podrías editar la respuesta? , me gustaría conocer mi error, porque en ninguna parte estoy heredando ninguna clase, todo esta separado, de acuerdo a las clases de su base de datos, según yo, la clase Animales, cuidador y refugio, no estoy heredando de ninguna parte, ni tan siquiera hago uso de ella en el repositorio, ni en el interfaz, solo en el controlador, donde se inyecta la clase genérica

Comment: @Daniel ZocanController hereda de MyControllerBase, de donde la sacaste?

Comment: @Japv ya entendí , es mi `CustomController`, pero en realidad seria `ControllerBase`, dejo edito la respuesta, ya que esta se crea por default al crear un controlador desde visual studio, y en mi caso, yo personalizo mi propio controlador y `MyControllerBase` heredo al controlador base `ControllerBase`

Comment: @Daniel estas asumiendo mal en ningún momento el usuario dice que esta usando la web, tu asumes que si, y q tal si es una aplicacion de Windows Form o de Consola, o cualquier otra

Comment: @Daniel si vas a responder con ese grado de complejidad te recomiendo que edites tu respuesta, y dejes claro en dd usas la clase RepositoryGenerics, dd la instancias, dd la usas y como la usas, lo mismo con las otras clases, a tu respuesta le faltan detalles, debes enriquecerla si vas a responder con ese nivel de complejidad

Comment: @Japv pues nada, en mi repuesta la doy en base a un web api, en caso de que sea Windows Form o de consola o WPF, o cualquier otro témplate, solo se deja de usar esto `public class ZoocanController : ControllerBase`, quedando de esta manera `public class ZoocanController` segun tu respuesta y nomas se usa las clase genérica, que seria la interfaz y repositorio. `IGenericRepository` y `RepositoryGenerics`, y en este caso, solo necesitaria el `IGenericRepository` para poder retornar el listado a todas sus tablas, como `Animales`, `Cuidadores` y `Refugio`

Comment: Era de winforms, si. Perdondad no haber especificado, no sabía que se podía usar para web, mea culpa. Igualmente no es para ponerse así ninguno de los dos. Es una mera pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

si se puede crear una [clase generica](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes) para todas tus tablas que quieras devolver un listado. yo te recomiendo que creas una archivo que le pondras como nombre `Infrastructure`, en este tendras dos subcarpetas, que sera `Interfaz` y `Repository`

en tu interfaz crearas todos tus metodos, en este caso solo estas devolviendo una lista, e igual no estas llamando ningun id o cierto parametro,quedando de esta manera

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAllAsync();
}
```

en tu repositorio llamaras la interfaz que realizaste `IGenericRepository`, y a tu DB, en mi caso uso Entity Framework, lo cual a mi db, lo llamare `DBContext`

```
public class RepositoryGenerics<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
  private readonly DBContext context;

  public RepositoryGenerics(DBContext context)
  {
    this.context = context;
  }
  public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAllAsync()
  {
    return await context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
  }
}
```

en este caso estoy usando `class` porque no estas agregando ningun id, o algun otro parametro para los metodos, solo retornas un listado, si quieres hacer un `where id`, tendras que cambiar `class` por una `clase generica`, en tu clase generica agregas tus parametros a utilizar en el where o x procedimiento, si estas usando net6, debes agregar la inyeccion de dependencias, de esta manera

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), (typeof(RepositoryGenerics<>)));
```

finalmente en tu controlador lo usaras de esta manera

```
public class ZoocanController : ControllerBase
{
  private readonly IGenericRepository<Animales> Animales;

  public ZoocanController(IGenericRepository<Animales> Animales)
  {
      this.Animales= Animales;
  }
  
  public async Task<ActionResult<IReadOnlyList<Animales>>> ObtenerListadonAnimales()
  {
    return await Animales.GetAllAsync();
  }
  
}
```

y de esta manera tienes tu clase generica, la interfaz lo puedes utilizar para cualquiera tabla, siempre y cuanto devuelvas un listado, y asi sucesivamente lo vas agregando al constructor

```
private readonly IGenericRepository<Animales> ZoocanAnimales;
private readonly IGenericRepository<Cuidadores> ZoocanCuidadores;
private readonly IGenericRepository<Refugio> ZoocanRefugio;
```